# Something about critical sections

Tags: java, multithreading, native, monitor

Imagine a situation where multiple processes try to use a shared resource.

You can protect it by using a java monitor ( for example - synchronized methods).

But what if your classes must obey to that protocol?

request method - critical section - end method

Any process is the only one executing the request and end methods simultaneously, thanks to the synchronized blocks, but what about the core of the critical section?

Using other constructs like Semaphores or Lock/Condition you can make it easily, but with native monitor you are bonded to the fact that a synchronization is identified by a block that cannot cross multiple methods.

If you use a `boolean` that tells you whether the resource is busy (calling `wait()` right after) or not, deadlock can occurr!

So, what could be a good solution for this?

Comment: You should definitely look to split this out into two separate questions instead.  You can pick one question here to ask, and leave the other for a bit later.

Comment: You can even post the other one at the same time.

Comment: Do stuff -> call synchronized method for your critical section -> Do stuff

Comment: its hard to read and understand your question. Provide some code samples to clarify your question.

Comment: Done. I will open a thread with the other question! Thank you and sorry for the original topic!

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine a situation where...

There's a name for that, it's *long transaction*, and if you think you need to implement it, that's a sign that it may be time to re-think your design.

Why it's bad, and how to avoid it is a book-level topic.

Here's one book that covers it pretty well:

[https://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)